# ngOnChanges stops firing when input property is changed

Tags: angular

I am using an Angular @Input property to set boolean values to the child component like this. I'm expecting that 'Inside ngOnChanges' be printed every 2 seconds. However, I can see that it printed only twice and then change detection does not take place. Can some one please advice how do I fix this?

**Parent component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <my-app-child [repaint]="triggerRepaint"></my-app-child>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  triggerRepaint: boolean
  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit(){
  setInterval(()=>{
     this.triggerRepaint = false;
     //do something
      this.triggerRepaint = true;
   }, 2000);
  }
}
```

**Child Component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app-child',
  template: `
    <div>

    </div>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() repaint: boolean = false;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnChanges(){
     console.log('Inside ngOnChanges');
  }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That issue is coz of this 2 lines :

```
this.triggerRepaint = false;
//do something
this.triggerRepaint = true;
```

> Reason : Each time it will send true to the child component so it will
>   not considered as the change

Change that to :

```
//do something
this.triggerRepaint = !this.triggerRepaint;
```

**OR**

```
setInterval(()=>{
  this.triggerRepaint = false;
  //do something
  setTimeout(()=> {
    this.triggerRepaint = true;
  });
}, 2000);
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-change-time)**

---

### Please go through the below scenario for more detail in depth

> Change detection will not be called untill whole function executed ,
>   here what happens is once you called the function it goes into the
>   queue of execution once this and right after that Change detection
>   will be called

---

> **1) In your case**

```
setInterval(()=>{
     this.triggerRepaint = false;
     //do something
     this.triggerRepaint = true;
   }, 2000);
}
```

**Queue :**

```
this.triggerRepaint = false;
//do something     
this.triggerRepaint = true;
// change detection will be called -> Here last value will always be same after first execution
```

**Event Pool :**

```
Blank
```

---

> **2) Without setTimeout**

```
setInterval(()=>{
     this.triggerRepaint = !this.triggerRepaint;
   }, 2000);
}
```

**Queue :**

```
this.triggerRepaint = !this.triggerRepaint;
// change detection will be called -> Here last value will always be different from previous one
```

**Event Pool :**

```
Blank
```

---

> **2) With setTimeout**

```
setInterval(()=>{
  this.triggerRepaint = false;
  //do something
  setTimeout(()=> {
    this.triggerRepaint = true;
  },0);
}, 2000);
```

**Queue :**

```
this.triggerRepaint = false;
//do something
// change detection will be called -> last value always be false
```

**Event Pool : (Once the above queue is clear it will push below execution to the queue and execute)**

```
setTimeout
this.triggerRepaint = true;
// change detection will be called -> last value always be false
```

Comment: Will the first line this.triggerRepaint = false; not trigger change detection? I'm doing some task and then setting it to true.

Comment: @JyotiPrasadPal , no it will not trigger the change detection , once the execution queue is clear it will be called , in out case last execution queue line is this.triggerRepaint = true; , with setTimeout it will be takne out from the queue , this is called event looping

Comment: Can you please update your answer with the explanation that you have put in comments above. This would be helpful who is looking at your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the above solution doesn't work for you, it could be related to the changeDetection strategy used within the app.

If the parent of any of your components as changeDetection OnPush, this could result in changes not updating correctly.